# Is it possible to 'share' functions between multiple Node.js express servers?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have two separate node.js express servers running on different ports.

- on port 5000 is running an Authentication API that handles the register, login, and session verification.
- on port 6000 is running a Product API that handles the CRUD operations for the products.

When I create a new product I would like to verify the token found in the request header, so instead of copying over the session verification method from the Authorization API, I imported it, but for some reason, I get this error in the console when starting the app:  `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000`

Authorization API exports the method:

```
export const verifySessionToken = async (sToken: string) => { ... }
```

Products API imports the Method:

```
import { verifySessionToken } from '../../../auth/common/verify-session';
```

If I comment out the import from above, the app runs again.

Is it even possible to import methods from node apps running on different ports?
If it is, what would be the correct way of doing it?

Million thanks!

Comment: You're trying to directly import from one codebase into another? The correct way to split functionality would be to have said functionality live in its own module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you import functions from modules.  You don't import methods from servers.  And, it's perfectly feasible to import the same function for use in two separate servers either in the same nodejs process or in different nodejs processes.  The process of importing something from a module has absolutely nothing to do with a server or a port that server is running on.  You're just importing a function reference from a file that you can call later.

You do need to make sure that your code is properly modularized so that the process of importing the function doesn't have any unintended side effects such as trying to start another server that you don't want to start.  So, perhaps your function isn't properly modularized (put in its own sharable module)?

> Is it even possible to import methods from node apps running on different ports? If it is, what would be the correct way of doing it?

Yes.  It's very easy if you create your module properly and make sure that it doesn't have any unintended side effects.  If you show us the entire module that you're importing from, we can probably help you identify what you are not doing correctly.

FYI, just put this:

```
export const verifySessionToken = async (sToken: string) => { ... }
```

in its own file where both places that want to use it can then import it.

Comment: Thank you, friend! :) You've managed to enlighten me on many matters. I've managed to import the verifySessionToken function by separating it to its own file including all the other functions related to it. So that error was caused by a function that was living inside the main index.ts file where the app was listening to the port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run two servers sharing the same files. Why don't you just replicate your function in the other app ?

Comment: You *can*, because if they're both on the same machine, it's just a file reference. I *wouldn't*, because of unintended side-effects like the OP is experiencing.

Comment: @DaveNewton - We share code among different processes ALL the time.  Any NPM module you use can easily be used in many different apps at the same time.  There is zero danger in doing so and lots of advantages to proper modularity.  You DO have to design a proper shared module that doesn't have unintended side effects, but that that takes about 2 minutes to move the shared code to it's own file and then just use that file from two separate places.  Way better than maintaining two copies of the same code.

Comment: You asked: *Why don't you just replicate your function in the other app?*.  The answer is because then you're maintaining two separate copies of the same code.  A shared module is nearly always a better way to structure your code so you only have to maintain one copy of the code.

Comment: You would't have to maintain two files if you just  add as a git sub module

Comment: @jfriend00 It's certainly not "zero danger" because doing so requires manual intervention, while putting it in a proper module eliminates that overhead, however minimal. While I *have* done it (and still do), it's certainly not my preferred mechanism, if for no other reason than I don't necessarily control what machines my code is running on.

Comment: @DaveNewton - If you're creating the shared module, you control everything you need to control.  Just don't put any module initialization side effects in the module that have nothing to do with the code you're sharing.  It's really, really easy.  There is no risk at all once you learn how to do it properly.  And, doing it properly is as simple as putting one function in a file and exporting that function (as I show in my answer here).  And, doing it properly is a very useful thing to learn how to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm aware the mechanics are trivial. I don't have the luxury of sharing code across apps that way, and even if I did, I wouldn't put shared code in an application for local use in a different application. I don't believe that's an appropriate separation of concerns. YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Well, that's what you use modules/libraries, source code repositories like GitHub and version control for.  There are huge maintenance advantages to sharing common code, not copying common code.  With the proper module management, you can only upgrade a project to a newer version of a module when you want to and have reason to, but when you do, the maintenance work will have largely been already done for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 I specifically said putting code in modules was my preference. I specifically said importing directly from another app’s code base as the OP has done is a recipe for a mess. I’m not sure who you’re talking to at this point because it doesn’t seem to have much to do with what I’ve said.

Comment: @DaveNewton - I missed the part where you said "putting code in modules was my preference".  In fact, I see why I missed it.  You never said that until a few minutes ago.  We can be done now that you have actually communicated that.

Comment: @jfriend00 “[...] while putting it in a proper module eliminates that overhead, however minimal [...]” The OP was specifically discussing not-that, and this answer claimed you couldn’t do it. I said you can, but shouldn’t, because of unintended side-effects. I responded to your first comment, which iirc was edited after I replied to it, because there is clearly not zero danger in directly referencing another app’s code, Whatever.